# Parsing Private-Key format 1.2 with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dnssec, powerdns

Working with DNSSEC and PowerDNS I am trying to parse a Private Key format 1.2 with Python so I can get the corresponding Public key.

Using pydnssec ( https://github.com/tomas-mazak/pydnssec ) I was able to generate the private key.

They key looks like this:

`Private-key-format: v1.2
Algorithm: 8 (RSASHA256)
Modulus: s3cHXKgqP4JY6yQSGRVftnz+omoBfwDbc7BoDGzQsMVa0eQpASVb0QryPfejfG3K/F9tEPzYgeMMjzwlDuHnK46DGS7WynKDMUPYDYSb8dvRGyD2Ef027ReAB5OYstSnIXRbyj+NzpaF1V0R3Xlg2mXnHO2UZ+PjmDKx+4353D/pUyqoVoNvZi4AESnWBC11ZlNsaxX5ILy/RlYLxQ7Kobh3pfWtHiXPqnyAy1sJFaCyVCGng4a9lUzfMRIbEYATSoDIfNN8rUMMU2c9eUax1Lwp370AbuTycVVXQYafwoRmMN/R9YmYAFHdmwsnWe+yv/ErDGYyoYGn/W0P44UpUQ==
PublicExponent: AQAB
PrivateExponent: Xiw5qr972/O0YT9+V7dFkGcq32MtAc4bWivZjZuULw6Ax98oPTezZJCP6UCHg4XBnIkenGlx20afkpIHCDY2rj6MQKy5fWZ1vWZSe1V414N3yPqU5X+wUN2iC1fCKyU3xnBeslSDP0LxW7MI6uUEk9YhXqa014dYKMeBafVohdAKiPWnxrhTFafDqrYj0ltt76y+ffUK7tuTvzkaCB+MQawGG96nf4Y9VaFHl2yt1jYcL7Bd7QpWmw0snCpYroeIOStce2l9mcgZeedPzp2hL0xWdYMoiqZgcc+lkt8g8jBkHd9lUKykvtaiQ3s9egGtMlOl+ULt/MGlSE6VbHTsoQ==
Prime1: y4xJLcfVptBD/Mr8rMi70zlbS01VomMYi2GBsROPmwWN8gVTY3yjo7VcBFTMegW0nfVNIjwmCKWQ6GL8s54Zf8qSG2cpUGQZrNoym7efzeGPYyg4THzg7XU3+vEFlt7FVjLZ30UeKEMGVNAf6A9BADvh1XNR7/3VvzAOSr8JQ20=
Prime2: 4bYGrbHrCNATTWm+0l8i2ACsGEhKOa4YMOU5pKm2p/DoI0cfDd5yfPqwwdYPyufQbfQMiEaWM8HlRBvSZs3YD+n31bkmjhsOOQCyI+iHX7jkScM5JUodyFRbAG+743dWJOSkiqLTwuhuK66TZo6fdTjDxnjt2s/7KH5gDW5e6vU=
Exponent1: KM38tZLD/+bsWjcPJEwxawyqgpQEQMOA3iAz8Z2sQjWA2S28I8uOunjW839UZnnSVYAhcGWCcmVOgWempRNipT2kwJ2TqKwIgaBUWOccwBchuY0MjDjUloXTLRk4N6B9CuSyzJF8lDGriUEXxFuaekOG6FVv7Z6DRQqLMuzNHJk=
Exponent2: KM38tZLD/+bsWjcPJEwxawyqgpQEQMOA3iAz8Z2sQjWA2S28I8uOunjW839UZnnSVYAhcGWCcmVOgWempRNipT2kwJ2TqKwIgaBUWOccwBchuY0MjDjUloXTLRk4N6B9CuSyzJF8lDGriUEXxFuaekOG6FVv7Z6DRQqLMuzNHJk=
Coefficient: Pohsb1j3g9Em+luwFMyddO7jKtdP76kdQx+xqDz6ctOgGmyjKx/Fu6m2CMGc3uIBOfKNEb6zLpKHvetzhKlDGNb24ca8S0WWNCW3wutZ32GvR8gpTHVQraAbOhPEDVSk1QuDAOWI/jEkf7OGuPUj8/GmLGU1rflYvNr1nLrD3yI=`

I am trying to load the newly generate key from string/file and extract the public key.

The result would be something like this:

`257 3 8 AwEAAepo5mc4fDlpcaGx9+hTNSZwC1LIGyPtK8VjdS0wfAaQa8FAwtrVXO9aQRYjKrUnHEtE52olCbJMlVygDllb3d8UcKyWRo+gm7YO02f/ckhqKghM9LVUWxfsxFWI4jA7zJ9I8+ACc3WN9PRAb7dHTLctjTejJ1/DQi6KoWidLHqTKoaOo8FMfCZrCc9XJ3DqCwEPIQQwe2SdpWwAByouQH4OBdaVx6nu9uHvroKsU/kRxW18vySWk+LnFjg0hI1UId/6Ud/3fS7RW/V6B+wJFd9XdfZtfAJDIsVQiBfvm0HguBIB6nMfSEBnuuEb/dyUVadtWTHtp8fY/+Y/2XY/0bM=`

The python Crypto library doesn't seem to have support for this. Any ideas on how to do this?

`key = Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.importKey(externKey=keystring)`

Gives me:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pubkey.py", line 14, in <module>
    key = Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.importKey(externKey=keystring)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 682, in importKey
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported`